# jQuery simulate to press enter

Tags: jquery, triggers

Hello I am trying to simulate pressing enter in an input box
I been trying with:

```
 var e = $.Event('keypress');
 e.which = 13;         
 $('#inputdId').trigger (e);
```

But it didn't work out. Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You may also need to set `e.keyCode = 13;`

Comment: I tried with e.keyCode = 13; and also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
var e = jQuery.Event( 'keydown', { which: 13 } ); jQuery('input').trigger(e);
```